# X-Editable javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, plugins

I am using this plugin called [X-Editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html).

A little stuck on how to accomplish this so I figured I would see if anyone else has used it or knows what to do.

Here is what my Page looks like:

[screenshot http://imageshack.us/a/img850/4817/yko7.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img850/4817/yko7.png)

You can simply click on the text and it will allow you to edit it right there and there.

Now, as my end result, all I am trying to do is get the values from each of the rows but cant seem to figure it out.

Per the doc, I set my code up like the section here: "Creating new record". I just dont know how to get the values or the object when I click on my button.

Anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

http://jsfiddle.net/8vTPL/1/

This should at least get you going in the right direction. This example uses basic jQuery concepts to loop through collections. In your case, you want to loop through all of your table rows (line 7):

```
$('#tbl_values tbody tr').each(function(ix,obj...
```

get the id of each row/record (line 8):

```
$(obj).attr('id')
```

then loop through each table-data and x-editable element per that row (line 9):

```
$(obj).children('td').children('.editable').each(function(e_ix,e_obj...
```

get the id of each column/field (line 10):

```
$(e_obj).attr('id')
```

and get the value of each x-editable element in the row (line 11):

```
$(e_obj).editable('getValue')[$(e_obj).attr('id')]
```

Alternatively, you could just get the object that X-editable stores as the value:

```
$(e_obj).editable('getValue')
```

Hope this helps.